# Is there a symbol like an "upbow" that occurs between notes in vocal and piano scores?

Tags: theory, notation

I'm looking at a hand-written score (with terrible handwriting) and I see something that looks like "upbow" (?) but it is between notes, and in a score without strings other than piano... It's a small "V" or check mark on the top-most staff line, and appears for SABT and bass and treble clef of a piano.

Elsewhere in the score is an "apostrophe" breath mark. So, I don't think this "V" is indicative of that, but given the quality of the hand-scrawling, it could be...

(I only see one "apostrophe" style breath mark. Perhaps the "V" is a different kind of breath mark?)

Comment: For the difference between the tick and the comma type breath marks: see [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/98481/breath-marks-different-symbols/121461#121461) post

Comment: The linked question provides the likely answer. When I've sung in choirs, a tick meant a quick breath that didn't interrupt the pulse; a "V" indicated a full breath that might impact the pulse, depending on the conductor.

Comment: Also, even in the event the question is closed, it would still be helpful to see images of 1) The "V", 2) "The "apostrophe", and 3) a particularly "messy" part of the score, for context. This will benefit anyone with a similar question or who reads this one.